# In Love Live episode 6, what were the results of each member in karaoke/dance?

Tags: love-live

I can't read the kanji, but I'm interested in what each member's score was.

[image: Karaoke/Dance Results]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Their Karaoke Score/Dance Result (the names in the note are their surnames):

- Yazawa Niko （矢澤 にこ）: 94/A
- Kousaka Honoka （高坂 穂乃果）: 92/A
- Minami Kotori （南 ことり）: 90/B
- Sonoda Umi （園田 海未）: 93/A
- Nishikino Maki （西木野 真姫）: 98/B
- Koizumi Hanayo （小泉 花陽）: 96/C
- Hoshizora Rin （星空 凛）: 91/AA